# python pptx not extracting all the text

Tags: python-3.x, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am trying to use `python-pptx` to extract all the text in a given slide.

> But it is missing some text from some text boxes.

code:

```
from pptx import Presentation

   def getPptContent(path):
     prs = Presentation(path)
     text_runs = []
     for slide in prs.slides:
         for shape in slide.shapes:
             if not shape.has_text_frame:
                 continue
             for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
                 for run in paragraph.runs:
                    text_runs.append(run.text)
     return text_runs
```

But it is missing some text, but when I try to `print` the contents of the slide
from `slide._element` I can see the `missing text` in the `xml`

Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: I think you might've opened this as an issue for the GitHub repo. The answer given there was that your search needs to be recursive as shapes can contain other shapes.

Comment: In addition to shapes within groups, shapes might be e.g. SmartArt, for which you have to traverse the nodes collection. Or tables, where you'll have to iterate over the cells collection. Charts? A whole order or two of magnitude more complex. Or embedded/linked objects.